# source setup.bash in install space does not work when deployed onto different machine

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-install, setup.sh, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install my catkin workspace on machine A to a directory (e.g. `/home/usera/catkin_ws/install`) and would like to use it on machine B in a different location (let's say a different user home, e.g. `/home/userb/catkin_ws/install`). My setup uses another workspace in /opt/overlay/ that is overlayed.

Now, on machine A everything works fine, when I source the setup.bash (therefore I check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, which is `/home/usera/catkin_ws/install/share:/opt/overlay/share:/opt/ros/kinetic/share`). Unfortunately, on machine B, sourcing setup.bash does not work, the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is `/opt/overlay/share:/opt/ros/kinetic/share`.

I have found the following ROS answers:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/243124/deploy-ros-package/?answer=243140#post-id-243140
- http://answers.ros.org/question/226581/deploying-a-catkin-package/?answer=226725#post-id-226725

So apparently ROS uses absolute paths and I need to mirror the install location in machine A to machine B, in order to get the install space working on machine B.

So my questions are:

- Is there a way to deploy the install space to machine B to a different location than on machine A (no location mirroring)?
- If not, what is the advantage of having absolute paths? As this makes deployment of ROS binaries via an install space very cumbersome in my opinion.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257487/source-setup.bash-in-install-space-does-not-work-when-deployed-onto-different-machine/) by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2017-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-03-21**:
`opt/overlay/share:/opt/ros/kinetic/share` doesn't look right, why is there no leading `/`? The install space should be relocatable, but the workspace it overlays needs to be on both machines (same as for binaries you built against). See: https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/490

**Comment by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on 2017-03-21**:
sorry, that was a typo. it is `/opt/overlay/share:/opt/ros/kinetic/share` of course. corrected this in the original question. the overlaid workspace is the same on both machines. I will take a look at the issue and come back with more information. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I resolved the problem. When I deployed my install space from machine A to machine B, I created a folder (let's call it `base`) containing some shell scripts and the `/home/usera/catkin_ws/install` and zipped it:

```
base - home - usera - catkin_ws - install - ...
     - a.sh
     - b.sh
```

More specifically, I created the zip file like this:

```
mkdir base
cp --parents -r /home/usera/catkin_ws/install/* base
cp a.sh b.sh  base
zip -r base.zip base
```

Unzipping `base.zip` on machine B led to the problem I described.

However, if I create the zip file like this:

```
mkdir base
mkdir -p base/home/usera/catkin_ws
cp -r /home/usera/catkin_ws/install base/home/usera/catkin_ws
cp a.sh b.sh  base
zip -r base.zip base
```

and unzip it on machine B, I can source the `base/home/usera/catkin_ws/install/setup.bash` and the created `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is correct.

It seems like the `--parents` flag of the `cp` command changed something in my deployed install space, however I have no idea what it changed and how this could even happen. Anyway, I am very happy that I was able to resolve this and maybe someone knows the reason of this.

---

Originally posted by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) with karma: 185 on 2017-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0